# The largest triangle between fuctions

Tags: functions, triangles, maxima-minima

*Hello,
I have been given this task, which I couldn't solve properly:*

---

There are given 2 functions:

$f(x) = 3xe^{-x}$

$g(x) = \frac{x}{2}$

and number $v$ is the x coordinate of their second intersection (not 0).

The task is to find parameter $u$, where $0 < u < v$, such that triangle formed by vertices $[0, 0], [u, f(u)], [u, g(u)]$ has maximal area.

Please take in mind, this is supposed to be a high school level solution.

---

My idea was to substract the area of triangle $T2=\{[0,0], [u, 0], [u, g(u)]\}$ from the area of triangle $T1 = \{[0, 0], [u, 0], [u, f(u)]\}$ which took me to this fuction: $\frac{3}{2} x^{2} e^{-x} - \frac{x^{2}}{4}$ and it's derivation $-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x} x (-6 + e^{x} + 3 x)$. Then searching for extremes:

$-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x} x (-6 + e^{x} + 3 x) = 0$

$-6 + e^{x} + 3 x = 0$

...which is probably not elementary solvable and I would have to use something like Lambert W function, which is not high school level Math.

Is there a better way to approach this problem or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The area of the triangle is:
$$S=\frac12\cdot u\cdot 3ue^{-u}-\frac12\cdot u\cdot \frac u2\\
S'=3ue^{-u}-\frac32u^2e^{-u}-\frac u2=0 \Rightarrow u\approx 1.04869.$$

Comment: if you could only express u that would be what I need... (in exact form)

Comment: It confirms your equation: $e^u=6-3u$, which can be solved by numerical methods like Newton’s method or bisection method.